# how to copy files correctly in maven for angular project

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, maven

I integrated my nrwl nx project into my Spring boot application inside my src/main/ressources folder. In this step of my pom:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/WebApp/nosi-frontend/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project nosi-backend: /home/hasan-can/Schreibtisch/Nossi/nosi-backend/target/classes/WebApp/nosi-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-cwd -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project nosi-backend: /home/hasan-can/Schreibtisch/Nossi/nosi-backend/target/classes/WebApp/nosi-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-cwd
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: /home/hasan-can/Schreibtisch/Nossi/nosi-backend/target/classes/WebApp/nosi-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-cwd
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: /home/hasan-can/Schreibtisch/Nossi/nosi-backend/target/classes/WebApp/nosi-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-cwd
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/hasan-can/Schreibtisch/Nossi/nosi-backend/target/classes/WebApp/nosi-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-cwd
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException (UnixException.java:92)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException (UnixException.java:111)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException (UnixException.java:116)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setMode (UnixFileAttributeViews.java:254)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setPermissions (UnixFileAttributeViews.java:276)
    at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions (Files.java:2080)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFilePermissions (FileUtils.java:1997)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile (FileUtils.java:1978)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

It can not copy the files ts-node-cwt but the file exists so I am a bit confused as to why it can not be copied. Can someone tell me what I have to do or if you need a specific file please tell me I will post it.

I am using version 10.9.1 of ts-node

EDIT UPDATE:

This is my project.json it is the same as angular.json but for nrwl:

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../../static",
        "index": "apps/nosi/src/index.html",
        "main": "apps/nosi/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "apps/nosi/src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/nosi/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["apps/nosi/src/favicon.ico", "apps/nosi/src/assets"],
        "styles": ["apps/nosi/src/styles.scss"],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

This is just the target part. My mvn version is 3.6.3

Updated pom.xml with directory:

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.0</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v14.21.1</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.14.17</npmVersion>
<!--                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>-->
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/WebApp/nosi-frontend/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/WebApp/nosi-frontend/dist/nosi-frontend</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I just changed the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated your problem and successfully copied files that you want, so plugin configuration is correct.

I have few suggestion that may help you as well:

- in the logs I can see that your trying to copy `node_modules` folder - that is not a good idea - you should just copy `dist` folder by changing `pom.xml` line to
  `<directory>src/main/resources/WebApp/nosi-frontend/dist/nosi-frontend</directory>`
- you can omit copying angular app files to `src/main/resources/static/`, just by configuring `outputPath` in `angular.json` file if that is your intention

Comment: Hi @AleksanderSzporka  How did you notice the version is the problem? I tried to use the maven command line inside intellj the inside mvn version is 3.8.6 my local on laptop is 3.6.3 but even with the inside maven I got the same error. Also which directory do you mean to change to dist? Workingdirectory? I changed my project.json output directory to static. I will post it as well

Comment: I updated my maven to 3.8.6 but still it does not work

Comment: Hi @natyus it is intended to copy node_modules folder? 
if no -> change pom.xml line to `<directory>src/main/resources/WebApp/nosi-frontend/dist/nosi-frontend</directory>`
if yes -> check that directory `/home/hasan-can/Schreibtisch/Nossi/nosi-backend/target/classes/WebApp/nosi-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-cwd` exists and have sufficient permissions

Comment: Hi copying the dist folder helped me out thanks. Now I have another problem which I will post as another question :)

Comment: Thanks and maybe you can help me with my new question as well :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887146/compiling-webapp-and-spring-boot-together-causes-routing-to-not-work

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that include the SPA (angular dist) into spring boot server.
build in local (but we can use maven also to call node for build) and set the ouput to /resource/public then spring boot will register it as homepages.

here the detail tutorial i have follow : https://dev.to/jakmar17/deploying-angular-application-inside-spring-boot-57g7

so then the SPA will accessible from spring boot uri